# The domain of the function $f(z) = e^{z^2−(1+i)z+2}$ is all complex numbers.

Tags: complex-analysis

The domain of the function $f(z) = e^{z^2−(1+i)z+2}$ is all complex numbers ?

I think it's correct, but I still don't know the fullest reasoning

Comment: Why wouldn't it? It's an entire function.

Comment: @Peter Hello and welcome to Math.SE! Please, even if you have doubts or you think you are not correct, try to show *your* reasoning: what makes you think that the domain is $\mathbb{C}$? Show your research about this. If you are blocked at some point, write where and why. Try to improve your question this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should read: $f(z) = e^{z^2−(1+i)z+2}.$

The function $g(w)=e^w$ has the domain $ \mathbb C.$

Furthermore: $f(z)=g(z^2−(1+i)z+2).$

Comment: The image of the circle $|z − z0| = R$ under a linear mapping is a circle with a
(possibly) different center, but the same radius ? In your opinion, this clause is correct ?